# check img size and form before upload

Tags: php

i have the following problem,
i m trying to check the file size and the format of some pics, using FOR EACH
 here's the code

```
....

$check = 0;
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
  {
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];


    $allowedExts = array("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "JPG");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    $file_ext=strtolower(end($temp));  


    if ($file_size > 2097152)
      {

        $errors = 'Bigger than limit';
        $check = 1;
      }
    else if (in_array($file_ext,$allowedExts) === false) 
      {
        $errors = 'Wrong format';
        $check = 2;
      }
  }
}

if  ($check = 1)
  {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("Κάποιο από τα αρχεία σας ξεπερνάει το όριο των 3mb. Παρακαλώ ελέγξτε τα αρχεία σας!!!")'; 
    print '</script>'; 

  }
else if ($check = 2)
  {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("Παρακαλώ εισάγετε μόνο αρχεία σε .jpeg και .jpg  format!!!")'; 
    print '</script>'; 

  }

else if ($check = 0)
  {

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
      {
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];


        $allowedExts = array("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "JPG");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $file_ext=strtolower(end($temp));  
        if (($file_size <= 2097152) && (in_array($file_ext,$allowedExts) === true))
          {

            $desired_dir=$Kwdikos_Sunergath.'_'.$Hmeromhnia_Musthriou.'_'.$date_added;
            if(empty($errors)==true)
              {
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                  mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
                  {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
                  }
                else
                  {                                 //rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                    rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;                
                  }
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO mpla mpla mpla)");
              }
          }
      }
```

so when i m trying to uplod a file less than 2mb it makes the $check = 1 and i dont know why.... if i skip the check code it works...

Comment: Use "==" in your if statements.

Comment: @rrrfusco thnx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `==` instead of `=` while checking.

Try like

```
if  ($check == 1)
             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what [Shankar Damodaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799955/1456376) said, I would say, check for an image like this:

```
$imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]);
if (2 != $imagesize[2]) {
    // if not JPG handle error
}
```

Take a look at the manual: [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

---

If you need to extract the extension of a file you can use this, instead of splitting the string:

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Take a look at the manual: [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($file_size > 2097152 && $file_size <= 1mb )
{
    $errors = 'Bigger than limit';
    $check = 1;
}
/*WRONG*/
if ($check = 1)
{
    ......
} 
/*CORRECT*/
if ($check == 1)
{
    .....
}
```

I added and operator in your if statement try it and use `==` in if statement. 
I hope it will work.